# How to adjust screensize or resolution?

Tags: 14.04, resolution

Here's what happened: My power went out for a few minutes the other day and when I turned my computer back on my screen was like zoomed-in, both on the desktop and on the internet (every page I pull up is too big for the screen and requires me to scroll left and right to see it all.) I checked and the resolution is set at 1024 x 768 (4:3) and that is the highest selection there was. I never checked the res before so I don't know if that's normal. But whatever it is, something happened to my comp when the power went out. Any ideas? Do I need to adjust the res in the terminal?

Comment: What's the brand and model of your screen?

Comment: I'm not sure. On the monitor it says acer x213w tco 03.

Comment: Increase your resolution to 1366x768

Comment: How do I do that? I went into Settings, but it's up as high as it can go? Is there a way to adjust it in the terminal?

Comment: Do you still experience the problem? Have you tried rebooting the computer and turning the monitor off and on again? Looking at the specs of your screen the native resolution should be 1680 x 1050.